# C#: How to shorten that XML appending?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have that XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<backupatmail>
  <backup id="0">
    <foldername>TestFolder</foldername>
    <backupdate>09/10/2015</backupdate>
    <comment>Sample comment text is here</comment>
    <numberofparts>7</numberofparts>
    <lastsucceed>Test.007</lastsucceed>
  </backup>
  <backup id="1">
    <foldername>TestFolder2</foldername>
    <backupdate>09/10/2015</backupdate>
    <comment>Sample comment text is here</comment>
    <numberofparts>15</numberofparts>
    <lastsucceed>Test.015</lastsucceed>
  </backup>
</backupatmail>
```

Now, I want to append new node(?):

```
<backup id="999">
  <foldername>testing1</foldername>
  <backupdate>99/99/9999</backupdate>
</backup>
```

I wrote following code:

```
    public static void AddBackupToXML()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(GlobalSettings.appDefaultFolder + "backups.xml");

        XmlElement backupNodeNew = doc.CreateElement("backup");
        XmlAttribute backupId = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
        backupId.Value = "999";
        backupNodeNew.Attributes.Append(backupId);

        XmlNode nodeTitle = doc.CreateElement("foldername");
        nodeTitle.InnerText = "testing1";

        XmlNode nodeUrl = doc.CreateElement("backupdate");
        nodeUrl.InnerText = "99/99/9999";

        backupNodeNew.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
        backupNodeNew.AppendChild(nodeUrl);

        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(backupNodeNew);

        doc.Save(GlobalSettings.appDefaultFolder + "backups.xml");
    }
```

Is there any shorten way to do that and also keep simplicity at beginners level?

Comment: It really depends.  If you're only appending one node, then who cares?  If you append 1000s, you may want to parameterize it, or pass the entire XmlElement in this function.

Comment: I need to be ready to handle about 200-1000 nodes to add...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). It has more simple API for working with XML and your code will look like

```
var file_name = GlobalSettings.appDefaultFolder + "backups.xml";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file_name);
var backup999 = new XElement("backup",
    new XAttribute("id", 999),
    new XElement("foldername", "testing1"),
    new XElement("backupdate", "99/99/9999")
    );

xdoc.Root.Add(backup999);
xdoc.Save(file_name);
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I have similar approach in other place so it's clean&neat to have similar solution in that part code :-)

Answer (score 0):

How I did it plenty of times, using copy special feature of visual studio http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/ I generated the classed describing the xml structure, handle it really clean and easy from code and transfomed when required with  System.Xml.Serialization https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815813 in xml doc or whatever was the need.

The same way from xml to c# object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to not use the xml api directly. Rather, use the model object then serialize and de-serialize it. It's much cleaner in my opinion and the code to do what you actually need is only 3 lines once your have the generic serializer in place.

What you can do is de-serialize your object into an actual "backupatmail" object and then call backupatmail.BackUpItems.Add(your new item here) and then deserialize it back into a string.

This approach is slower than using LinqToXml during runtime but most of the time a extra millisecond or more isn't a big deal.

Here's the serialization/ deserialization code.

```
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    public class SerializationUtils
    {
        public static T Deserialize<T>(string data)
        {           
            XmlSerializer objSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var reader = new StringReader(data))
            {
                return (T)objSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            XmlSerializer objSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            XmlSerializerNamespaces emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new [] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
#if DEBUG
            settings.Indent = true;
#else
            settings.Indent = false;
#endif

            using (var stream = new StringWriter())
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                objSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj, emptyNamespaces);
                return stream.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

and for your use.

```
string mailItems = GetXmlStringFromSomewhere();
var objMail = SerializationUtils.Deserialize<BackUpMail>(mailItems);
var newItem = new BackUp() { FolderName = "testing1", BackupDate = DateTime.Now};
objMail.BackUpItems.Add(newItem);
var strMailWAddedItem = SerializationUtils.Serialize(objMail);
```

Here are your entity classes.

```
public class BackUpMail
{
    public List<BackUp> BackUpItems {get;set;}
}

public class BackUp
{
 [XmlAttribute("id")]
 public string ID {get;set}

 [XmlElement("foldername")]
 public string FolderName {get;set;}

 [XmlElement("backupdate")]
 public DateTime BackupDate {get;set;}

 [XmlElement("comment")]
 public string Comment {get;set}

 [XmlElement("numberofparts")]
 public string NumberOfParts {get;set}

 [XmlElement("lastsucceed")]
 public string LastSucceed {get;set}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the code, just parameterize it.

```
public static void someOtherMethod(){
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(GlobalSettings.appDefaultFolder + "backups.xml");

    // some loop..
      doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(createNode(id[i], foldername[i], backupdate[i]));

    doc.Save(GlobalSettings.appDefaultFolder + "backups.xml");
}

public static void createNode(string id, string foldername, string backupdate)
{
    XmlElement backupNodeNew = doc.CreateElement("backup");
    XmlAttribute backupId = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
    backupId.Value = id;
    backupNodeNew.Attributes.Append(backupId);

    XmlNode nodeTitle = doc.CreateElement("foldername");
    nodeTitle.InnerText = foldername;

    XmlNode nodeUrl = doc.CreateElement("backupdate");
    nodeUrl.InnerText = backupdate;

    backupNodeNew.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
    backupNodeNew.AppendChild(nodeUrl);
    return backupNodeNew;
}
```